# how to set add and subtract value min=0 and max=10 with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

how to set add and subtract input value using custom button wiht rule min=0 and max=10, it's almost similar to `<input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="10" />`, here is my code examples, i created button add and subtract to change the input value with jquery, but the value not have min and max rule, what should i do to create it?

```js
$(function(){

  var x = $('input').val();
  
  $('#plus').click(function(){
    $('input').val(++x)
  });
  
  $('#minus').click(function(){
    $('input').val(--x)
  });

});
```

```css
.n{display:flex}

input{margin:0 8px 0 8px}

.b{
padding: 4px;
background: yellow;
cursor: pointer;
}

.b:hover{
background: blue;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Quantity</p>
<div class="n">
  <div id="minus" class="b">
    minus
  </div>
  <input type="text" value='0'>
  <div id="plus" class="b">
    plus
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check my answer, added simple logic inside  $('input').val()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){

  var x = $('input').val();
  
  $('#plus').click(function(){
    $('input').val(x<10?++x:x)
  });
  
  $('#minus').click(function(){
    $('input').val(x>0?--x:x)
  });

});
```

```css
.n{display:flex}

input{margin:0 8px 0 8px}

.b{
padding: 4px;
background: yellow;
cursor: pointer;
}

.b:hover{
background: blue;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Quantity</p>
<div class="n">
  <div id="minus" class="b">
    minus
  </div>
  <input type="text" value='0'>
  <div id="plus" class="b">
    plus
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for on keyup event, you can simply add the same logic.

Comment: yes, That's what I mean